# Google App Engine endpointscfg.py command starting 1.8.6 does not accept argument -f

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints

This problem just started in Google App Engine version 1.8.6:

When executing command (based on instruction https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/gen_clients):

```
endpointscfg.py get_client_lib java -o . -f rest your_module.YourApi
```

We get error:

> endpointscfg.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f

The command with argument -f execute without any issue for Google App Engine version 1.8.5.

With 1.8.6, I don't know how to generate client end point library, because of this error.  If you have a workaround, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use get_client_lib to generate client library, rest format is the only option. So if you intend to generate a Rest client library, simply remove ".f rest" option. And you will get your Rest client without any problem.

If you want to use RPC client (which is currently only supported in iOS client). Please refer to https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_ios for instruction.

I think one piece might be missing from the documentation above. In order to get the api-v1-rpc.discovery, you need to run get_discovery_doc command like following:

endpointscfg.py get_discovery_doc -o . -f rpc your_module.YourApi

Hope it helps.